Logs Not Generated in log.html When Running Robot Framework Task via APScheduler
When running a Robot Framework task directly, the logs are generated in the log.html file as expected. However, when the same task is registered as an APScheduler job and executed by the scheduled task, the logs do not appear in log.html.
Here is the code for the scheduled task:
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from apscheduler.triggers.interval import IntervalTrigger
import robot
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Define the function to execute the Robot Framework task
def run_robot_task(robot_file_path):
    # Generate report directory
    report_dir = "./"

    # Run the Robot Framework task
    robot.run(robot_file_path, outputdir=report_dir)

# Create the APScheduler background scheduler
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()

# Define the scheduling time, using IntervalTrigger to execute every 60 seconds
job_trigger = IntervalTrigger(seconds=60)

# Provide the actual Robot Framework file path
robot_file_path = "./3.robot"

# Register the job
scheduler.add_job(run_robot_task, job_trigger, args=[robot_file_path], id="robot_task",
                  name="Execute Robot Framework Task", next_run_time=datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=5))

# Start the scheduler
scheduler.start()

# Keep the main thread running to ensure the task continues to schedule
try:
    while True:
        pass
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    # Shutdown the scheduler
    scheduler.shutdown()

Here is the code for  3.robot
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Library    DateTime
Library    OperatingSystem
Library    BuiltIn


*** Variables ***

${DETAILS_BUTTON_XPATH}    //*[@id="details-button"]
${PROCEED_LINK_XPATH}    //*[@id="proceed-link"]
${SRARCH_SHOW_HIDE}    //*[@id="search_show_hide"]

*** Test Cases ***
Open Browser With Custom Proxy
    ${version}=    Evaluate    robot.__version__
    Log    Robot Framework version: ${version}  console=True
    Log    Robot Framework version: ${version}    level=INFO
    Log    This is an info message    level=INFO
    Log    This is a debug message    level=DEBUG
    Log    This is a trace message    level=TRACE

btw this is log.html, and only the first step has log


If someone encounters a similar situation, you can change the executor type from threadpool to processpool, which should resolve the issue. However, the exact reason is still unclear.

it will fix in rf7.2

https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/5255
